# SSL error when using https FCM

Tags: ssl

I have implemented FCM for web using fcm documentation. 
Everything'll be fine if I set url like : 'http://xxx' I have no error.
But when I set url : 'https://xxx..', I get error:

"Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script."
code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
"Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."

Can anyone show me how to fix this error?

Comment: No one can explain this problem ?

Comment: ........................

Comment: Could you mark the answer trollkotze gave? It works

Answer (score 16):

This is a general problem when wanting to test service workers in a local development environment without proper SSL certificates. It is not specific to Firebase Messaging but pertains to Service Workers in general.

Here is the solution I found when using Google Chrome: [Testing Service workers locally with self-signed certificates](https://deanhume.com/testing-service-workers-locally-with-self-signed-certificates/)

Unfortunately, I don't know yet how to circument the issue with other browsers, but probably there must be similar ways.

For Chrome, you need to start a new instance of Chrome, with some flags telling it to ignore SSL certificate errors for your local origin:

In Linux (and maybe Mac):

```
google-chrome --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://127.0.0.1 --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo
```

The `https://127.0.0.1` here is the location where your app (and service worker) is hosted locally. You might need to adjust this to use the appropriate port, if serving on a different port than the standard HTTPS port 443, e.g. `https://127.0.0.1:3000`, when serving your app over HTTPS on port 3000.
The `--user-data-dir=/tmp/foo` is necessary to start a new instance, with a new user profile, if another instance of Chrome is already running.

In Windows (might vary, depending on where your chrome.exe is):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:1123
```

Again, you might have to adjust the port.

Comment: The Windows command didn't work completely for me, but this did:`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:8443 --user-data-dir=C:\tmp` (specifically the additional `--user-data-dir` flag)

Comment: New Exception : `This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).`

Answer (score 1):

Easier method that worked for me:
Just paste `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` in your chrome browser, and Enable the setting that says something like "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost."